# PHP errors are not shown

Tags: php, error-reporting

I've got an PHP file with an error in it, but I don't know where it is and there is no error reporting, but I enabled error reporting in php.ini and in the script.

Why can't I see the error?

Comment: Did you reboot your web-server? Try to run script from shell php also

Comment: How do you know there an error in it?

Comment: Check `display_errors` ini setting too, alongside of `error_reporting`.

Comment: If it's a syntax error, then php -l <filename>.php from the command line should tell you where the error is

Comment: If it's a parsing error, then using `ini_set()` or `error_reporting()` won't help. Configure your `php.ini` or `.user.ini` or via `.htaccess` parameters.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Enabling error display in php via htaccess only](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6127980/enabling-error-display-in-php-via-htaccess-only)

Comment: Plenty of possible dups [here](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=show+php+errors).

Answer (score 3):

Make the first four lines of your page look like this:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', TRUE);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', TRUE);
```

This will override your error echoing settings elsewhere so you can track down your problem. And of course, don't forget to do a `phpinfo();` if you suspect there's a missing or misconfigured dependency.

Answer (score 0):

Try enabling errors in PHP:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', TRUE);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', TRUE);
```

If you still don't see anything and you are using Linux and Apache try looking into `/var/log/apache2/error.log` you can see the live log `tail -f /var/log/apache2/error.log`