# Server error when loging in Joomla

Tags: joomla

The site has been just moved to a new host. Everything works as it is supposed, but when trying to log in as administrator, I am given the following error:

```
Internal Server Error

The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Please contact the server administrator, webmaster@localhost and inform them of the time the error occurred, and anything you might have done that may have caused the error.

More information about this error may be available in the server error log.
```

Any idea of what can be wrong? htcaccess file is renamed to htcaccess.txt

Comment: check what is in error log file

Comment: it is complitely empty.

Comment: you have to enable error logging then, either through htaccess (have a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6127980/enabling-error-display-in-php-via-htaccess-only)) or via your hosting control panel

Answer (score 1):

If you follow everything in **[here](http://docs.joomla.org/Copying_a_Joomla_website)** you will find what you forgot.

Typically configuration.php is what is forgotten. In addition I strongly recommend [Akeeba backup](https://www.akeebabackup.com/). Something to think about next time.

Comment: I have followed to tutorial, but still cannot get to the back-end. As try to log in, I am given the 500 server error.

Comment: @JohhnyP have you enabled php logging as Marko suggested? With a 500 error it has to be the server that's not communicating. Does `public $live_site` indicated the proper server in your `configuration.php` file?

Comment: Yes it does, but I have finaly found the problem. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I have finaly figured it out. The htaccess.txt was in the root directory. What I had to do is to rename the .htaccess file in administrtor folder.