# How to save PHP errors into files automatically for each directory?

Tags: php, linux, apache, apache2, wampserver

We have a linux hosting from a company and if any php script on that server has any PHP FATAL errors, it is automatically written into a file separately for each directory. So, although PHP errors are off in my scripts, I can still get the error logs as log files in each directory of those PHP scripts.

What I know that I can enable PHP error from configurations for my local server and set a specific file path which will contain all PHP errors from all scripts AND from all directories. But, I would love something automatic and separate like them.

How can I achieve the function in my local servers that we have on our hosting? Have they written a special script or is that a PHP ini settings that I should know?

**UPDATED**
Let's say public_html directory has three A, B and C directory or folder. There are three scripts a.php, b.php and c.php in those directories respectively. So, each of those directories will have error_log file that can contain all errors of those scripts separately. Let's say, folder A has also another script called d.php. But, errors from a.php and d.php will be written under public_html/A/error_log file.

Other directories will also have following files:

public_html/B/error_log file

public_html/C/error_log file

Comment: Can you define what you mean by "directory" here.  It would be very usual indeed to want to log errors for each individual directory within a single web directory to different places.

Comment: Folder. Please see my updated example too.

Comment: This question appears to be answered in this port http://stackoverflow.com/a/6128036/2310830

Comment: The error_log has to be set like I typed out in the answer. Since, there is no slash, the path of error file is relative and the error file is written for each directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In php.ini, I had to enable the following setting and restart the server. It worked like I needed.

```
error_log = "error"
```