# How can I display PHP errors through htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, php-ini

Ok , I work at a place where I'm not allowed to touch the php.ini file because the server serves so many websites ... However, I was told that I can display php errors through htaccess so I can debug my code because right now , my PHP screen comes blank and it's not helping .. how can I display php errors through my local htaccess file without having to access php.ini ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use these commands to enable error reporting and set the error level using your .htaccess file.

```
php_flag display_errors on
php_value error_reporting <error level>
```

You can also define error reporting in some kind of php config file using error_reporting().

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use:

`php_flag display_errors on`

in your .htaccess file

Comment: Hmm.. also, look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6127980/enabling-error-display-in-php-via-htaccess-only

Answer (score 0):

> php_flag display_startup_errors on
>   php_flag display_errors on
>   php_flag html_errors on
>
> ## enable PHP error logging
>
> php_flag  log_errors on
>   php_value error_log  /httpdocs/domain name/PHP_errors.log

Using htaccess, you may specify a maximum size for your PHP errors. This controls the size of each logged error, not the overall file size. Here is the general syntax:

## general directive for setting max error size

log_errors_max_len integer

Ref Link : http://perishablepress.com/advanced-php-error-handling-via-htaccess/