# allow htaccess file apache

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I want to turn off all the php errors from .htaccess file. I tried with following stackoverflow question.

[Enabling error display in php via htaccess only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6127980/enabling-error-display-in-php-via-htaccess-only)

.htaccess file:

```
php_flag display_startup_errors off
php_flag display_errors off
php_flag html_errors off
php_flag  log_errors on
php_value error_log  /home/petstail/public_html/PHP_errors.log
```

And in my httpd.conf file, in virtualhost I put directory like,

```
<Directory "/home/website/public_html">
    Options All MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

ERROR LOG:

```
Invalid command 'php_flag', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not
included in the server configuration
```

But, still I am getting internal server error (500). What should I do? What configurations am I missing?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you restarted the server?

Comment: FIrst check your Apache error.log to see why 500 is coming.

Comment: Is PHP installed as an Apache Module?

Comment: **php_value** and **php_flag** are strongly discouraged in most Apache servers, and will often give a 500 error. They belong in a php.ini file (which you may have to create), with slightly different syntax.

Answer (score 1):

"defined by a module not included in the server configuration" is most probably the reason. It tells you, that it is not allowed to set `php_flag` inside the `.htaccess` file. You need to to set those value in the vHost configuration – or even better in the php.ini.

Comment: How can I do it? can you elaborate your answer please.. I don't know much about server configurations..

Comment: In that case you are maybe better with [using `error_reporting( 0 )` in your application](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php)… I just don't want to post a whole tutorial on Apache configuration here – there are a lot of those out on the web.