# How can I run wordpress php files in a subdomain?

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, .htaccess

I'm trying to install wordpress 3.9.1 in a subdomain, I know it works because I have the same version in localhost using XAMPP.  The subdomain is working (I tested it with html and php files), but no wordpress file is running, I only get blank pages (not errors, just blank pages).  The databases are created, the wp-config.php is edited and the privileges are granted, but still I cannot get the wordpress files to run.  This is my configuration:

OS: CentOS 6.5
Provider: Digital Ocean
PHP: 5.3.3
Apache: 2.2.15

my VirtualHost looks like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName blog.domain.com
  DocumentRoot /var/www/blog/
  <Directory "/var/www/blog/">
    Options Indexes FollowSymlinks
    AllowOverride None
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: You need a more specific title, it should be a question. Tell us what the result is when going to the site.

Comment: I edited question and results: I only get blank pages.  Thanks.

Comment: Go to `site/index.php`, otherwise create a file phpinfo.php and place in that blog folder and go there in URL. Phpinfo.php should contain `echo phpinfo();`

Comment: I already did it, it is working, it prints the php info.

Comment: Make sure there is an `index.php` and turn error reporting on, it would be best to use `.htaccess` in this case.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6127980/enabling-error-display-in-php-via-htaccess-only

Comment: Do you have access to the error log to see where it's breaking?

Comment: You sir @StevieG are a genius! I had a bad character in my salt keys in the wp-config.php, enabling the error reporting lead me to the bad line.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To configure wordpress subdomain as you need:

1) configure the virtualhost, example

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerAdmin you@domain.com
DocumentRoot "/var/www/blog/"
ServerName blog.domain.com
ErrorLog "/var/log/blog.domain.com-error_log"
CustomLog "/var/log/blog.domain.com-access_log" common
<Directory "/var/www/blog/">
    Options +Includes
    AllowOverride all
</Directory>
```

2) Configure wordpress to use the subdomain:

Place the following line of code to the end of the file wp-config.php

```
define('WP_HOME', 'http://blog.domain.com');
define('WP_SITEURL', 'http://blog.domain.com');
```