# Script doesn't work after including PHP file

Tags: php

I have some problems when I include a PHP file. I am trying this for the first time so I don't really know how to get this is working. The PHP file doesn't respond anymore when I include something. Here is some code:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Testing opus class</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php
            include('eedce5ed141dd72b552b7abdeb48ede3ddebc0c4.php');
            $opus = new opus();
            print "Test"; // It isn't printing "Test" over here
```

Comment: Do you get any errors? (Error reporting: `<?php
  ini_set("display_errors", 1);
  error_reporting(E_ALL);
 ?>`) Also what's in the include file?

Comment: Thanks @Rizier123, I did something wrong with an array in the other file. Also: Do you maybe know how to enable the error display for other files (For all files).

Comment: Made an answer! (not sure but it could be that there is a setting in the `php.ini` file! Maybe take a look here: http://php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php)

Comment: You can enable it for the entire site with [.htaccess](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6127980/enabling-error-display-in-php-via-htaccess-only)

Comment: I just turned it on in the php.ini. Everyone: thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if you get any errors with error reporting:

```
<?php
    ini_set("display_errors", 1);
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
?>
```

Also make sure you don't have any error's in the file which you include!