# server does not see php codes after editing in File Manager or File Zile with Notepad, what do I do?

Tags: php

I uploaded a project to my host and after editing php codes with File Manager or File Zila with Notepad ++ they are no longer running, although there are no errors when loading, what do I do?

Comment: what do you mean by "does not see" ?

Comment: my server knowledge is very low and I ty to study in HTML, CSS, PHP, ...

Comment: you did not answer me, what do you mean  ? Your old code is executed ?

Answer (score 1):

It is maybe possible since you have edited it in file manager, you have some errors. You are claiming you do not see errors, maybe your server have error_reporting/displayin_errors off. Check it in your PHP.ini.

For more info how to enable it: 
[How to get useful error messages in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/845021/how-to-get-useful-error-messages-in-php)

Comment: TKS ! Mike, but when uploading file with File Zila I got message " All files have been succesfuly transfered "... and even so my code not runing ...error_reporting/display_errors is off and I can not set it on of at my host

Comment: You can enable it in .htaccess
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6127980/enabling-error-display-in-php-via-htaccess-only