# PHP AltoRouter - can't get GET request

Tags: php, routes, altorouter

For some reason I am not able to start AltoRouter. I am trying the most basic call, but nothing is happening. How can I make it work?
My **index.php** file looks like this:

```
    <?php

    include('settings/autoload.php');

    use app\AltoRouter;

    $router = new AltoRouter;

    $router->map('GET', '/', function(){

        echo 'It is working';
    });

$match = $router->match();
```

**autoload.php**:

```
<?php

require_once('app/Router.php');
```

Comment: Any error message? Blank page? what's happening in your index.php?

Comment: There are no errors  and the page is blank.

Comment: Show your errors with this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5911964/cannot-get-php-display-errors-enabled

Comment: Still 0 errors (I am running php on linux, and any error is showing in the terminal);

Comment: did you try to get it via browser? just to be sure you're getting something

Comment: hey @Sasha, any news on this? I'm getting the same problem and can't get fixed.

Comment: @Paolo which PHP-Version are you using? I think it's an syntax error because some Language constructs aren't supported in older PHP versions. In this case, error Reporting may not be enabled.

Comment: This is the package you're using, right? https://github.com/dannyvankooten/AltoRouter. If so, the class in that repository is not under any namespace. Then, why are you using `app/AltoRouter`?

Comment: My issue details: https://github.com/dannyvankooten/AltoRouter/issues/124

Comment: Check the link http://altorouter.com/usage/processing-requests.html. According to it, AltoRouter would not process the request. Add the piece of code after `$router->match();` and then it will work.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your Problem is that AltoRouter, according to the [documentation](http://altorouter.com/usage/processing-requests.html) (and in contrast to the [Slim Framework](http://www.slimframework.com), which *seems* to have the the same syntax), won't process the request for you, it only *matches* them.
So by calling `$router->match()` you get all the required information to process the request in any way you like.
If you just want to call the closure-function, simply modify your code:

```
<?php

// include AltoRouter in one of the many ways (Autoloader, composer, directly, whatever)
$router = new AltoRouter();

$router->map('GET', '/', function(){

    echo 'It is working';
});

$match = $router->match();

// Here comes the new part, taken straight from the docs:

// call closure or throw 404 status
if( $match && is_callable( $match['target'] ) ) {
        call_user_func_array( $match['target'], $match['params'] );
} else {
        // no route was matched
        header( $_SERVER["SERVER_PROTOCOL"] . ' 404 Not Found');
}
```

And voilà - now you'll get your desired output!